# mysql_query - different behaviour on different servers

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different servers: 
one running Plesk Panel (PHP 5.2.13 & MySQL 5.0.45-community-nt),
and the other running Zend Server 5.5 (PHP 5.2.17 & MySQL 5.1.50-community).

I have a table in mysql DB on both servers as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `num` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `txt` text NOT NULL,
      `ste` bigint(5) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

i run the following php code on both servers:

```
    mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

    if(!mysql_query("insert into test_table(num,txt) values(1,'sd')"))
    {
        echo "ERROR OCCURED.
".mysql_error();
        mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Successful insertion";
        mysql_query("COMMIT");
        exit;
    }
```

i get the query successfully run on my Plesk Server (with warnings - if run SHOW WARNINGS query, i get "Field 'ste' doesn't have a default value", but the row is inserted and mysql_query returns true)

but on my Zend server, mysql_query returns false and the same error is shown. the row is not inserted.

i need the row to be inserted ignoring warnings. i spend a whole day on this and is out of options now.

please  help me on this. thanks lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though the MySQL running on your Zend server is running in Strict Mode. This means that what would otherwise be a warning becomes a fatal error.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) for information on server modes and how to change them, try disabling Strict Mode, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply. i set the sql-mode to "" and it works fine. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

can you use the IGNORE keyword? Insert IGNORE into ..... Not sure if it's a good idea though